# Function on Matlab producing zero for no apparent reason

Tags: matlab, math

Consider the function:

```
function R = bumpfun(x,y)
if x > 0 & y > 0
   R = (exp(-1./x.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-x).^2)).*(exp(-1./y.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-y).^2));
else
   R = 0;
end
```

Yet when I attempt to compute `bumpfun(-10:.1:10,-10:.1:10)`, I get `0`, which makes no sense since for `x > 0 & y > 0` I should get something nonzero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a `logical` array as the conditional of an `if` statement, it will only evaluate to true [if *all* elements of the array are `true` *and* it is non-empty](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html).

> An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise, the expression is false.

```
if [true false]
    disp('Will not run')
end

if [true true]
    disp('Will run')
end

if [false false]
    disp('Will not run')
end
```

In your example, the output of `X > 0 & Y > 0` is about half `true` values and half `false` values which causes the `if` expression to evaluate to `false` and the `else` block is executed instead.

What you will want to do instead is to use `X > 0 & Y > 0` to create a logical mask which you can then use to manipulate the result.

```
mask = x > 0 & y > 0;
R = (exp(-1./x.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-x).^2)).*(exp(-1./y.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-y).^2));
R(~mask) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

x and y are not scalars so `x > 0 & y > 0` is not scalar as well and this is why your if condition doesn't work as expected. try indexing instead:

```
function R = bumpfun(x,y)

R = zeros(size(x));
nzIdxs = x > 0 & y > 0;
x = x(nzIdxs);
y = y(nzIdxs);
R(nzIdxs) = (exp(-1./x.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-x).^2)).*(exp(-1./y.^2)).*(exp(-1./(1-y).^2));
```